# Can a Google TV app display Live TV (without overlays)

Tags: android, video, google-tv, television

Is it possible for an app to display exactly the same as the Live TV app while the app is running?  That is, for the HDMI input to be passed to the HDMI input unmodified.

I would like to use my GTV remote keyboard to control my computer (over VNC, Synergy, or other protocols) that is connect to the HDMI input while displaying the conventional video signal through the GTV.  My primary interest is to control the computer, as an HTPC, with one fewer keyboard laying around.  I'm not interested in one of the available VNC apps due to the performance burdens of HD video playback through VNC over the network.

The only information I could find closely related to this was inquiries into adding overlays on top of Live TV.  It is clear that overlays are not possible but I could find nothing that addressed showing Live TV without overlays.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i know of to do what your asking is to connect the remote to the computer via Bluetooth, yet you will still need the driver to interpret the controls

Comment: The Sony NSZ-GT1 remote is ZigBee, so direct-connection options are fraught with challenges such as the mystery of what ZigBee hardware works (if any) with OS X as well as controlling two devices with one remote that isn't designed for such use.  Has Google provided any documentation at all on their GoogleTV-specific APIs?